# How to bind default json data in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

How do you bind default json data in knockoutjs as stated?

For example:

```
var initialData = [
{
    "employee": [
      {
          "dotnet": [
            {
                "name": "sam",
                "age": "25",
                "yoj": "12"
            },
            {
                "name": "raj",
                "age": "28",
                "yoj": "13"
            }
          ],
          "db": [
            {
                "name": "sam",
                "age": "25",
                "yoj": "12"
            },
            {
                "name": "raj",
                "age": "28",
                "yoj": "13"
            }
          ]
      }
    ]
}

]
```

The code structure above is the one I prefer. I also want to use a foreach loop.

Comment: Please, update your question to explain where do you want to bind this data, and what do you want the foreach for.

Answer (score 0):

Binding is done with the data-bind attribute

```
<span data-bind="text: myVariable"></span>
```

You use ko.observable() to create a variable for 2 way binding.

```
var employeeModel= {
    employeeName: ko.observable(),
    employeeAge: ko.observable(),
    employeeYoj: ko.observable()
};
```

ko.observableArray() to support arrays.

```
var employeeArray = ko.observableArray();
employeeArray.push(employeeModel);
```

This link will get you started.
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html